# How to see customers of WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm taking over two wordpress+woocommerce websites. Individual customers buy products in the websites.

In the first website, I cannot find `Customers` (or `Clients` in French) in the sidebar:

[image]

In the second website, I can find `Customers` in the sidebar. But all the information is gray.

[image]

Does anyone know how to see the list of customers in WooCommerce?

Comment: I've never seen something like that. It seems you need a special permission for that. What happens if you triy to enter directly via url? some error must appear. It may be because a plugin? what role do you have? admin? editor?

Comment: OK, I just tried `https://www.firstwebsite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-admin&path=%2Fcustomers`, it told me that I don't have the right to see this page. But why everything is gray for the second website?

Comment: It seems you don't have the correct Role. Are you sure you're Admin? What about plugins?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm the admin... "What about plugins?" ==> What do you mean? You think they are using plugins or you think I can use other plugins to see the list of customers?

Comment: I think they could be using a plugin to limit the "permission" on some parts of the page. That's why some roles can't see the costumers unless you are basically an admin.